# Sort on $-values (US formatted numbers with commas as the thousands separator) in fields

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, ubuntu, debian

My trivial test shows that `sort` can sort on $-values (like $2,734, $278,280, etc), the US formatted numbers with commas as the thousands separator, just fine:

```
$ echo -e '$2,734\n$278,280\n$26,845' | sort
$2,734
$26,845
$278,280

$ echo -e '$5,088\n$26\n$8,714' | sort -r
$8,714
$5,088
$26
```

But why it does not work for me any more when I'm sorting them when they're in fields?

```
$ cat test.md
9.|||85,000|$5,088|NEW|2.99%
8.|||6,086|$348|NEW|0.1%
8.|||566|$26|NEW|0.02%
8.|||492,900|$8,714|NEW|0.71%
7.|||25,737|$180|NEW|0.14%
6.|||2,821|$511|NEW|0.4%
5.|||14,980|$2,734|NEW|2.17%
4.|||85,578|$376|NEW|0.02%
4.|||173,750|$18,369|NEW|10.79%
4.|||1,019,133|$40,388|NEW|7.3%
3.|||3,692,661|$25,244|NEW|20.08%
3.|||15,303,963|$202,471|NEW|14.83%
29.|||1,000|$32|NEW|0%
27.|||100,000|$1,000|NEW|0.18%
26.|||27,752,808|$490,971|NEW|0.65%
```

The `cat test.md | sort -t'|' -k5 -r -g` gives exact output as above. And even sorting on `-k4` doesn't work for me:

```
$ cat test.md | sort -t'|' -k4 -r -g
8.|||566|$26|NEW|0.02%
8.|||492,900|$8,714|NEW|0.71%
4.|||173,750|$18,369|NEW|10.79%
27.|||100,000|$1,000|NEW|0.18%
9.|||85,000|$5,088|NEW|2.99%
4.|||85,578|$376|NEW|0.02%
26.|||27,752,808|$490,971|NEW|0.65%
7.|||25,737|$180|NEW|0.14%
3.|||15,303,963|$202,471|NEW|14.83%
5.|||14,980|$2,734|NEW|2.17%
8.|||6,086|$348|NEW|0.1%
3.|||3,692,661|$25,244|NEW|20.08%
6.|||2,821|$511|NEW|0.4%
4.|||1,019,133|$40,388|NEW|7.3%
29.|||1,000|$32|NEW|0%
```

And `cat test.md | sort -t'|' -k4,4 -r -g` gives exact output as above as well.

All I want to do is to sort that US formatted numbers with commas as the thousands separator field in reverse numeric order.

There must be something obvious that I'm missing, but my mind is blocked now, and I have no further ideas. Please help.

This is under Debian WSL:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster

$ uname -rm
4.4.0-19041-Microsoft x86_64

$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.30
```

Comment: fwiw, initial comment is incorrect ... true, the example is sorted 'correctly' but only because of the first digit ... try `echo -e '$2,600\n$800\n$35\n' | sort -r` and you'll see that `sort -r` does not sort correctly

Comment: Oh...!!! Thanks for pointing that out @markp-fuso. Now how about sorting on `-k4`, why it isn't working for me either?

Comment: again, re: new example ... `sort` does not do what you think; try `echo -e '$568\n$2,734\n$278,280\n$26,845' | sort`; `sort` is working on the length of the field and then sorting by character

Comment: I know, I know, you just pointed out sorting on $-values doesn't work, @markp-fuso. I just put in one of many more tests that I did. Somehow all of them sorted 'correctly'.  It's an easy fix as I can remove that "`$`" easily. The problem is why `-k4` is not working? I.e., I'm afraid that even I've removed that "`$`" sign, it'll still not working for me.

Comment: sure, but also update the question with the **correct/expected** output

Answer (score 0):

One idea for sorting on data with multiple delimiters (in this case `|`, `$` and `,`) is to pull the 'sort' column, strip out all secondary delimiters, append said data to front of line, sort numerically, then strip off the first column.

One idea using `awk` to pull 5th field to front of line minus the `$` and `,`:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{new1=$5;gsub("[,$]","",new1);print new1"|"$0}' test.md
5088|9.|||85,000|$5,088|NEW|2.99%
348|8.|||6,086|$348|NEW|0.1%
26|8.|||566|$26|NEW|0.02%
8714|8.|||492,900|$8,714|NEW|0.71%
180|7.|||25,737|$180|NEW|0.14%
511|6.|||2,821|$511|NEW|0.4%
2734|5.|||14,980|$2,734|NEW|2.17%
376|4.|||85,578|$376|NEW|0.02%
18369|4.|||173,750|$18,369|NEW|10.79%
40388|4.|||1,019,133|$40,388|NEW|7.3%
25244|3.|||3,692,661|$25,244|NEW|20.08%
202471|3.|||15,303,963|$202,471|NEW|14.83%
32|29.|||1,000|$32|NEW|0%
1000|27.|||100,000|$1,000|NEW|0.18%
490971|26.|||27,752,808|$490,971|NEW|0.65%
```

We now pipe this to `sort`:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{new1=$5;gsub("[,$]","",new1);print new1"|"$0}' test.md | sort -t'|' -k1,1nr
490971|26.|||27,752,808|$490,971|NEW|0.65%
202471|3.|||15,303,963|$202,471|NEW|14.83%
40388|4.|||1,019,133|$40,388|NEW|7.3%
25244|3.|||3,692,661|$25,244|NEW|20.08%
18369|4.|||173,750|$18,369|NEW|10.79%
8714|8.|||492,900|$8,714|NEW|0.71%
5088|9.|||85,000|$5,088|NEW|2.99%
2734|5.|||14,980|$2,734|NEW|2.17%
1000|27.|||100,000|$1,000|NEW|0.18%
511|6.|||2,821|$511|NEW|0.4%
376|4.|||85,578|$376|NEW|0.02%
348|8.|||6,086|$348|NEW|0.1%
180|7.|||25,737|$180|NEW|0.14%
32|29.|||1,000|$32|NEW|0%
26|8.|||566|$26|NEW|0.02%
```

Now pass through `cut` (or `sed` or another `awk`) to strip off first field:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{new1=$5;gsub("[,$]","",new1);print new1"|"$0}' test.md | sort -t'|' -k1,1nr | cut -d'|' -f2-
26.|||27,752,808|$490,971|NEW|0.65%
3.|||15,303,963|$202,471|NEW|14.83%
4.|||1,019,133|$40,388|NEW|7.3%
3.|||3,692,661|$25,244|NEW|20.08%
4.|||173,750|$18,369|NEW|10.79%
8.|||492,900|$8,714|NEW|0.71%
9.|||85,000|$5,088|NEW|2.99%
5.|||14,980|$2,734|NEW|2.17%
27.|||100,000|$1,000|NEW|0.18%
6.|||2,821|$511|NEW|0.4%
4.|||85,578|$376|NEW|0.02%
8.|||6,086|$348|NEW|0.1%
7.|||25,737|$180|NEW|0.14%
29.|||1,000|$32|NEW|0%
8.|||566|$26|NEW|0.02%
```

Which leaves us with the initial data sorted by the 5th field.

**NOTE:** with a bit more coding could do `sort|cut` inside the first `awk` ...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the result order is not strictly in reverse numeric order. I've done more tests and found out the final solution. Please see my answer instead. If you'd like to change yours to 1. remove `$`. 2. sort 3. add `$` back, I can accept yours as the answer. thx

Answer (score 0):

As you may be able to tell, the phrase *"US formatted numbers with commas as the thousands separator"* comes from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507678/, which is what I was trying to duplicate. Apparently there are some minutia details that I've overlooked.

Here is how to properly sort `-k4`:

```
$ cat test.md | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sort -t'|' -k4 -r -h
26.|||27,752,808|$490,971|NEW|0.65%
3.|||15,303,963|$202,471|NEW|14.83%
3.|||3,692,661|$25,244|NEW|20.08%
4.|||1,019,133|$40,388|NEW|7.3%
8.|||492,900|$8,714|NEW|0.71%
4.|||173,750|$18,369|NEW|10.79%
27.|||100,000|$1,000|NEW|0.18%
4.|||85,578|$376|NEW|0.02%
9.|||85,000|$5,088|NEW|2.99%
7.|||25,737|$180|NEW|0.14%
5.|||14,980|$2,734|NEW|2.17%
8.|||6,086|$348|NEW|0.1%
6.|||2,821|$511|NEW|0.4%
29.|||1,000|$32|NEW|0%
8.|||566|$26|NEW|0.02%
```

And for sorting on $-values, just like @markp-fuso pointed out, it doesn't work. But for my specific case, it's an easy fix for me as I can remove that "`$`", and no need to keep it in my file.